# Why do we need continuous random variables since they can be approximated by discrete ones?

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, motivation

I do not understand the motivation of developing the theory of continuous random variables. Given simple discrete random variables, the continuous ones can be well approximated.

Comment: Simple reasons are because they are easier to work with directly and because the approximation procedure you suggest would be a pain if one had to use it every time. For example to compute the probability that the number of successes amongst 10000 tries in a fair game is less than 5200 by performing the summation would be insane.

Comment: You mean like we don't need irrational numbers, because they can be well approximated by rationals?

Comment: Why do we need continuous anything since we can always approximate with discrete ones? :)

Comment: You can think of the theory of continuous random variables as the theory of equivalence classes of sequences of discrete random variables. I think that, irrespective of what you call them, you need the theory. (Granted, I could be wrong, since I don't know a damn thing about the subject matter).

Comment: Just to add to nice mentioned examples: there is a shared opinion that discrete things are simpler as they are easier computable.
However, on the level of ideas it is easier for us to deal with objects that have a compact and clear shape - although being abstract at the same time. Perhaps, passing from discrete objects that you see around you to the continuity is one of the core abstractions one makes.

Comment: a) Why approximate anything when you can easily have exact? b) Anyway, the proposition that simple discrete rvs can well approximate all continuous rvs is fantastically dubious ... Vote to close.

Comment: @wolfies You might want to explain the assertion that "the proposition that simple discrete rvs can well approximate all continuous rvs is fantastically dubious".

Comment: @Did suggest try some counter-examples to help your thinking

Comment: @wolfies Sorry but the absence of justification, even when asked for, of such a strong assertion may lead people to find it "fantastically dubious".

Comment: @did what examples have you tried? Do you have any workings?

Comment: @wolfies OK, I briefly wondered whether the "fantastic" assertion in your comment was referring to some precise factoid I would have missed. The answer is now clear.

Comment: If @Did knows some precise (mathematical) factoid relevant to contesting wolfies' assertion, the simpler alternative to 3+ rounds of passive negative comments is to share it.  The meta fact that Didier is skeptical about wolfies' skepticism is of no great interest or importance to the site and it's not clear why so many comments are being expended on conveying it (and the equivalent everywhere else that wolfie may post, i.e., *comment stalking*).

Answer (score 4):

Many formulas and concepts simplify in the continuous limit. Sampling with and without replacement become equivalent, complicated binomial coefficient sums become smooth Gaussians, continuous symmetry groups appear in the multivariate Gaussian distributions.

For the same reason there are real numbers and continuous functions used in calculus, although everything could be replaced by finite computations or sequences of those.